# Add more rows to a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I am working with a travel API. When a user search for hotels,I am populating a GridView by bringing in 20 hotels at a time with the API.

At the end of the gridview, I am planning to show a button, "show more", when the user clicks that button, I want to call the API and bring more records and append them to the GridView's current records. Show more buttons will be enabled until the API says no more records exist (most of the time 100+ records will exist)

What is the best way to achieve this?

I do not want to keep the old records in the session variable and pad to that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use following kind of code....

```
private void showMoreButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = 1;
    while(i <= numberOfRowsToDisplay)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(yourDataStream[numberOfRowsDisplayed + i][0], yourDataStream[numberOfRowsDisplayed + i][1]);
        i++;
    }
    numberOfRowsDisplayed = numberOfRowsDisplayed + numberOfRowsToDisplay;        
}
```

You should fetch values from the data stream with regard to your API relevently...

Hope this helps...